# Политика конфиденциальности в Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать как решить проблему, связанную со сбором данных об установке программ на устройство без явно выраженного согласия пользователя. Сказано, что вся информация на этот счет должна прописываться в политике конфиденциальности приложения, но в самой консоли разработчика есть только возможность добавить URL ресурса с этой политикой. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, поэтому хотелось бы найти решение из данной ситауции

Comment: добавьте EULA, который будет содержать вашу политику, и показываться при первом запуске приложения с кнопкой *ПРИНИМАЮ*

Comment: Каким образом добавить?

Comment: Как диалог, который показывается при первом запуске